# How to write a Go type constraint for something you can take len() of?

Tags: go, generics, types

I am trying to write a type constraint for a Go program, that accepts "anything you can take len() of". But I can't really figure it out.

I want something like:

```
LenOf[m Measurable](m M) int {
    return len(m)
}
```

I tried a few things. Fx. this naiive thing, which do compile, but doesn't work on all types (like fx `[]User`):

```
type Measurable interface {
    ~string | []any | ~map[any]any
}
```

Then went on to something like, the below which not only makes the function signature for `LenOf()` extremely clunky, but also have clumsy to write on call sites (and still can't get it to compile)

```
type Measurable[K comparable, V any] interface {
   ~string | []V | ~map[K]V
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why? The builtin `len` is already "generic".

---

With that said, let's see why defining such a constraint is a bad idea. The Go spec has a paragraph — [Length and capacity](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity), that can help:

> If the argument type is a type parameter P, the call `len(e)` (or `cap(e)` respectively) **must be valid for each type in P's type set**. The result is the length (or capacity, respectively) of the argument whose type corresponds to the type argument with which P was instantiated.

The issues with writing an all-encompassing constraint for "measurable" types are:

- it includes arrays `[N]T`, where the array length is part of the type, so your constraint would have to specify all possible arrays you want to capture
- it includes array pointers `*[N]T`, which you can't easily abstract in a type constraint
- it includes maps, which forces you to capture keys `K` and values `V`, which may or may not be the same as `T`. Plus, `K` must implement `comparable`.

So you'd have to write something like:

```
type Measurable[T any, K comparable, V any] interface {
    ~string | ~[]T | ~map[K]V | ~chan T
}
```

which notably doesn't include arrays, and doesn't distinctly capture pointer literals, e.g. to match `[]*int`, you would have to instantiate `T` with `*int`.

You might simplify `V` away:

```
type Measurable[T any, K comparable] interface {
    ~string | ~[]T | ~map[K]T | ~chan T
}
```

The function `LenOf` then becomes:

```
func LenOf[T any, K comparable, M Measurable[T, K]](m M) int {
    return len(m)
}
```

but you still have to supply `K`, so you have to instantiate `LenOf` at call site with bogus types for the map key:

```
LenOf[string, int]("foo")
//            ^ actually useless
```

and you can't take advantage of type inference with the argument either.

In conclusion: just use `len`. Design your generic functions to work with type literals that support length, or add to the constraint only those types that your functions are reasonably expected to handle.

Comment: +1. In the spirit of [Roger Peppe's _Generics Unconstrained_ talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eU-w2psAvdA), the OP could simply pass a length function to the functions/methods that need that operation. For instance, `func Foo[T any](t T, length func(T) int) Whatever`.

Comment: that is particularly useful for computing length on arbitrary types that don't support `len` natively, e.g. structs, etc. It'd be just great if `len` could be passed as a first-class function here

Comment: Agreed. It feels weird not being able to call `Foo(map[int]string{1:"one"}, len)`. One day, perhaps.